# JSFiddle Oddness. Mobx failure after first time function

Tags: reactjs, jsfiddle, mobx

[Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/) is a state management tool often used with React. I'm trying to understand how the MobX tool works, using [their 'Ten minute introduction to MobX and React' tutorial.](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html) I'm playing with the [Task List JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mweststrate/wv3yopo0/) link provided at the bottom of the introduction page.

The JSfiddle works fine when first loaded. Change one byte of code, hit the JSfiddle run button and it crashes.  I'm trying to understand the JSFiddle crash and how to fix it.

When first loaded, I do see a console warning

```
VM48 babel.js:60934 You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. 
Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
```

After pressing the run icon in JSfiddle, I see the following error message

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mobxReact is not defined
    at <anonymous>:47:22
    at run (VM48 babel.js:60802)
    at check (VM48 babel.js:60868)
    at loadScripts (VM48 babel.js:60909)
    at runScripts (VM48 babel.js:60936)
    at transformScriptTags (VM48 babel.js:324)

(anonymous) @ Inline Babel script:4
```

This makes no sense to me.  How can the JSFiddle run correctly when the site is first opened, but fails after the run icon?  I can see MobX-react as an external reference.  Anybody understand what is going on here, and how to make corrections to JSFiddle (to enable me to really modify & play with MobX to understand what is really going on?)

Comment: JSBin has had some issues lately, very frustrating. Does [**this JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/qixutoxegi/1/edit?html,js,output) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you are trying to use the `mobx` library which is not present as a package.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mobxReact is not defined

To resolve this issue add a script tag in your HTML file to import the `mobx` library.

### Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="Mobx Sample">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/mobx@2.3.3/lib/mobx.umd.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

then in your JS file, you can import the `mobx` modules.

```
const { observable, autorun, computed } = mobx;
```